# How to change commit tag (author name) in CVS of a file already committed?

Tags: commit, cvs

I didn't have my own development environment, and copied a VM from a different user. I had did a `cvs update` and did a `cvs commit`.

I did not observe, but the `CVS\Root` file had the username of the other user instead of mine, and the changes were committed.

In the same way, there has been multiple commits by me, and there has been changes on top of that by other developers.

Now, how to change the author name of the committed file from the other user's name to my name?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't. CVS does not provide any capabilities to edit history.

The slightly longer answer is that you sort of can if you edit the `,v` file directly in the CVS repository. This requires that you have access to the server containing the CVS repository.

The `,v` file contains the revision history of the file you are working on and contains entries like this:

```
1.2
date    2005.11.20.22.43.32;    author Burhan;  state Exp;
branches;
next    1.1;
```

I suspect you would be able to change the author there but I have not tried this myself so cannot confirm if it will work.

Note that I do not recommend doing this unless you absolutely have to as you have the potential to corrupt the revision history. You'll have to balance that risk vs your desire to have the correct attribution and assess the situation appropriately.

Comment: Upvoted - but did not check manually editing the file. I'd suggest testing it on an example CVS before executing this type of direct-crude editing.

Comment: @UjjwalSingh Agreed. Testing out potentially destructive actions on a separate repository make sense.

Comment: @BurhanAli Do you know where cvs pulls the author name from? Is this the OS username?

Comment: @RyanR. Yes, it's from the OS username. This is the OS that the CVS repository lives on. A name might be pulled from elsewhere, but I do not have experience of that.